# Fineuploader dotnet core

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, fine-uploader

I'm trying to get write Controller (in asp.net core) code to handle my fineuploader requests but it keeps failing to see the request data despite whatever combination of [FromForm] / [FromBody] / "Content-Type": 'application/json' I use. Here is my uploader config in the view page:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: document.getElementById("uploader"),
        request: {
            endpoint: '@Url.Action("AddAttachment", "Util")',
            customHeaders: {
                "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()',
                "Content-Type": 'application/json'
            }
        },
```

And here is my controller code - not alot for now, I just literally want to see some data getting sent.

```
public JsonResult AddAttachment([FromForm] Object o){
         //var x = HttpContext.Request;
         //return Json(x);
         if(o == null){
             return Json("no data");
         }else{
             return Json(o);
         }
    }
```

and her is what I see fineuploader sending to the server via the network tab in the chrome devtools:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarySQwYoYovQOkoFU1f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"

876
------WebKitFormBoundarySQwYoYovQOkoFU1f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qquuid"

9ba04b80-b3d8-4e2d-8068-792dd77253bd
------WebKitFormBoundarySQwYoYovQOkoFU1f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfilename"

dohPlayDat.PNG
------WebKitFormBoundarySQwYoYovQOkoFU1f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqtotalfilesize"

3535659
------WebKitFormBoundarySQwYoYovQOkoFU1f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="dohPlayDat.PNG"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarySQwYoYovQOkoFU1f-
```

Can anyone see the mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything's wired up correctly, you should be able to see your file via `Request.Form.Files` in the controller.

I was trying to get it as a byte array by action's parameters but had no luck. Try this instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is an example of how you can bind all the fields from the file upload request, then use the file stream to write the file to a temporary file.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string qquuid, string qqfilename, int qqtotalfilesize, IFormFile qqfile)
        {
            // full path to file in temp location
            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

            if (qqfile.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await qqfile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }
```

For more information about using .NET Core to upload files you can have a look over here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: While this is good, I am looking for something that allows me to use the "multiple" option in Fineuploader, do you have some source for how the backend would be structured?